# BigQuery Data Transfer Service - Invalid Table Name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to set up a new Data Transfer Service from Cloud Storage to a BigQuery destination table.  But the GCP console states that the name is invalid for an existing BQ table.  Is this a bug?

For example, I would expect to be able to enter one of these table names for Destination Table, but the only ones that work are those without hyphens.

[image]

[image]

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables#table_naming), the table name *should* be valid.

> Table naming
>
> When you create a table in BigQuery, the table name must be unique per
> dataset. The table name can:
>
> ```
> Contain up to 1,024 characters.
> Contain Unicode characters in category L (letter), M (mark), N (number), Pc (connector, including underscore), Pd (dash), Zs (space).
> ```
>
> For more information, see General Category.
>
> For example, the following are all valid table names: table-01,
> ग्राहक, 00_お客様, étudiant.

**Update:** [Bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194922653) submitted to Google.

**Resolved**

> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195010531
>
> Changed
> status:  Assigned  →  Verified
> verifier:    →  ma...@google.com
>
> ma...@google.com added comment #5:
>
> Thank you for bringing this to our attention.
>
> I want to inform you that the issue has been resolved. Therefore, I will >proceed to close this issue.

Comment: It seems to be a bug.

Comment: are you sure that you haven't non printable character at the beginning or the end of your table name? A space for example.

Comment: quite sure that there are no extra characters

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure BQ table names used to not allow hyphens in their name (id) but apparently it has changed and now [we can use hyphens](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/TableReference).

So maybe data transfer has not updated its destination table validator and continued to refuse hyphens in tables name.

Comment: That's interesting: The API you mention allows hypens, but the documentation for BQ schemas does not - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas